# Click Checkbox is not working for protractor

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, protractor

My automation script for protractor could not click 1 checkbox. When I checked the original code, there is no id and most likely same except ng-touched/ng-untouched and male/female. Is there other way to click this checkbox?

The code as per below.

Checkbox for Male:

```
 <div ng-repeat="gender in genders" class="ng-binding ng-scope" style="">
                                                    <input type="checkbox" ng-
    model="usergender" ng-checked="usergender == gender.ParameterId" ng-
    click="genderId(gender.ParameterId, $event)" class="group1 genderChkBox ng-
    pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched" style=""> Male
                                                </div>
```

Checkbox for Female:

```
<input type="checkbox"ng-model="usergender" ng-checked="usergender == 
gender.ParameterId" ng-click="genderId(gender.ParameterId, $event)" 
class="group1 genderChkBox ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty"> 
Female </div>
```

I have tried with below code to check the Male,but receive this message error:  Failed: Male is not defined

```
var male = element(by.model('usergender'));
        male.click();
        expect(Male.getText()).toBe('Male');
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the latest protractor try this

```
$('.genderChkBox').click().then(()=>{
    expect(Male.getText()).toBe('Male');
});
```

Comment: tried the above code, I can see it already click on Male checkbox, unfortunately it still failed and return below message.

 Failed: Male is not defined

Comment: Your probably got to assign the div with a class or id or select it from the parent node

Comment: Yes, I already assign it to parent node.
 var Male = element(by.css('[ng-repeat="gender in genders"'));
 $('.genderChkBox').click().then(()=>{
    expect(Male.getText()).toBe('Male');
 });

This is working fine. But when I want to try to select female. I receive the error -  Expected 'Male' to be 'Female'. Is it because by default it is Male?

var Female = element(by.css('[ng-repeat="gender in genders"]'));
 $('.genderChkBox').click().then(()=>{
    expect(Female.getText()).toBe('Female');
 });

Comment: You don't really use ng-repeat as a selector. In your case you need to make your HTML more structured something like <label class="gender male"> Male <input type="checkbox"/> </label>

Comment: I don't have control on this original code. I tried use ng-click as a selector, and got   Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, [ng-click="genderId()"])

var Female = element(by.css('[ng-click="genderId()"]'));
  $('.genderChkBox').click().then(()=>{
     expect(Female.getText()).toBe('Female');
  });

Comment: Could you post the full html structure. coz i cannot see whether male and female is enclosed in the same div. it is still possible to select the correct node but not that straight forward, something like $$('div').get(2) blah blah

Comment: Here is the html structure with 3 post@Fan Cheung

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 required">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="year">Gender</label>
            <!-- ngRepeat: gender in genders --><div ng-repeat="gender in genders" class="ng-binding ng-scope" style="">

Comment: continue: 

<input type="checkbox" ng-model="usergender" ng-checked="usergender == gender.ParameterId" ng-click="genderId(gender.ParameterId, $event)" class="group1 genderChkBox ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" style=""> Male
            </div><!-- end ngRepeat: gender in genders --><div ng-repeat="gender in genders" class="ng-binding ng-scope">

Comment: last structure:

<input type="checkbox" ng-model="usergender" ng-checked="usergender == gender.ParameterId" ng-click="genderId(gender.ParameterId, $event)" class="group1 genderChkBox ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched ng-empty" style=""> Female
            </div><!-- end ngRepeat: gender in genders -->
           </div>

Answer (score 0):

```
var gander = element.all(by.model('usergender'));
   gander(0).click().then(function(){
   expect(gander(0).getText()).toBe('Male');
   expect(gander(1).getText()).toBe('Female');
});
```

or you can use below way to do single single action:-

```
var male = element(by.xpath('.//*[text()="male"]']));
male.click().then(function(){
expect(male.getText()).toBe('Male');
});
```

Comment: Thanks Yash. tried and got this message 
Failed: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression .//[text()="male"] because of the following error:
    SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string './/[text()="male"]' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: use this xpath instead .//*[text()="male"]

Comment: Updated ans. Have you tried 1st solution? It should work.

Comment: Hi Yash, i tried 1st solution, and its not click/check the Male checkbox. and got this message - Failed: gander is not a function

Comment: For the 2nd solution, it is failed with below error message. 

No element found using locator: By(xpath, .//*[text()="male"])

Comment: Please try 
.//*[text()='Male']